# Connect a API with a index.html through Gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn, api-design

I am trying to make work an app found in a public [GitHub repository](https://github.com/broadinstitute/SpliceAI-lookup/tree/master). It is an app created with Python that links an API with a WSGI HTTP Server (Gunicorn). When I run

```
set -x

NUM_THREADS=1
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=8080
TIMEOUT=1800
gunicorn -w ${NUM_THREADS} -t ${TIMEOUT} -b ${HOST}:${PORT}  server:app
```

I can use the API in my web browser as show below

[image]

What I want now is to link the API with a [index.html](https://github.com/broadinstitute/SpliceAI-lookup/blob/master/index.html) also found in the repository.

I am completely new in this topic but after reading documentation and other resources I have found that I need the keyfile and the certfile. Is this correct?? In the same repository, I have seen this script

```
set -x

#redis-cli flushall  #  clear all keys from redis

gunicorn -w 8 -t 1800 -b 0.0.0.0:80  -b 0.0.0.0:443 \
 --keyfile=../spliceailookup-api.broadinstitute.org.key \
 --certfile=../spliceailookup-api.broadinstitute.org.crt \
 server:app
```

but these two files are not in the repository and I am not sure if I need it.

In my browser I have tried `http://myremothost:8080/index.html`, `http://myremothost:433/index.html` when running the second script after deleting the lines strating --keyfile and --certfile, but I never get the interface I am looking for that looks like this https://spliceailookup.broadinstitute.org/